# Copy and overwrite one database into another using mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to copy my production database to my development environment. I copied website_production into mysql of my developemnt environment, so using SHOW DATABASES; now I have

website_development
website_production

as databases. How can I copy and overwrite all tables with their content from website_production into website_developemnt using mysql commands?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not MySQL commands but it's the easiest method, from command line:

```
$ mysqldump -u user --password=pass live_db_name | mysql -u user --password=pass -h localhost duplicate_db_name
```

Works on Windows terminal too.

Comment: Just to clarify - this is dumping **live_db_name** to **localhost** if anyone was confused

Answer (score 3):

[Glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2294775/glitch-desire) answer is usually good, but stored procedures and functions will not be in backup, therefore not copied to second database.

This is why I always do (`--routines` can be used instead of `-R` in command below):

```
$ mysqldump ${source_db} -R | mysql ${dest_db}
```

In fact, as I make a regular dump for backup purposes, I prefer to use the backup dump itself, therefore keeping it in a file:

```
mysqldump ${source_db} -R > ${source_db}.sql
mysql ${dest_db} < ${source_db}.sql
```

Note: I always avoid -u and -p parameters, for [security reasons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

Answer (score 0):

This solution I use for development environment Wordpress installs. In my case wp_options is the data I am to overwrite using values from wp_options_apache. The Example #1 query only overwrites 1 value per row updated on the table, but one could easily overwrite multiple columns by separating the assignments with commas such as in the second example.

Example #1:

```
    UPDATE `wp_options` AS a
    LEFT JOIN `wp_options_apache` AS b
    ON a.option_name = b.option_name
    SET a.option_value = b.option_value;
```

Example #2:

```
    UPDATE `old_data` AS o
    LEFT JOIN `new_data` AS n
    ON o.prime_key = n.prime_key
    SET o.username = n.username,
        o.password = n.password,
        o.email = n.email;
```